# How to detect database operation with JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, oracle19c

My scenario is the following: I have two applications, one allows the user to interact with the product catalogue (only GET API, totally passive) and the other one allows admins to create/modify/delete (crud API) products from catalogue.
In order to speed up the user application, I have been thinking about implement Spring Cache. The problem is that if an admin does any interaction with the database (Oracle19c), the app for the citizen does not detect anything.
How can I solve this problem?
In the past, I managed something like this with the Change Streams, by using Mongo or thanks to Spring Data Events, so that any operation to database could be perceived.
I would need to detect operation made on database to empty and reload my cache with always last updates and I do not if is possible.
Any advice?

Comment: You need to notify the application with the cache that the data was changed. There are so many options to do that: direct call, a message on a topic, notification from the DB (CQN if you are into native Oracle solutions). Externalising the cache to a separate process may be an option as well. Without knowing more about your apps and infrastructure at your disposal it is difficult to recommend something.

Comment: This CQN sounds interesting. How may I implement it with Spring Data JPA?

Comment: PS: there are other distributed L3 caches like Terracota(SAG) and Coherence(Oracle).  Maybe Oracle Coherence has already some interface for cache invalidation. Also Oracle DB itself can cache results of particular SQLs (result cache).